# PHP combine key value array and regular array

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays:

array1 :

```
[0]=>
string(10) "AAAAAAAAAAA"
[1]=>
string(10) "BBBBBBBBBBB"
...
```

and array2:

```
 [0]=>
 float(0)
 [550]=>
 float(55)
 ...
```

I need a result like this:

```
 "AAAAAAAAAAA"  : 0 : 0
 "BBBBBBBBBBB" : 550: 55
  ...
```

i.e. how to combine the arrays. How do i get that?

Comment: ur array is not proper

Comment: Please visit How to Ask : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Strictly speaking, that isn't really combining the arrays since there is no real correlation between them. (there's nothing linking the BBBBBBBBB and the 550). But you could just loop through one of the arrays and fetch the  matching counterpart from the other array (since the first array has sequential, numerical keys, it would be easier to loop the second one, increasing a counter each time, and fetch the content from the first array based on that counter)

Answer (score 2):

suppose you two arrays have the same length,

```
$keys = array_keys($array1);
$values = [];
foreach($array2 as $k=>$v)
{
  $values[] = $k.':'.$v;
}
$result = array_combine($keys, $values);
```

Answer (score 1):

The result you want is not clear... if each rows are just a string, this should work :

```
$a = [
    0 => "AAAAAAAAAAA",
    1 => "BBBBBBBBBBB"
];

$b = [
    0 => (float) 0,
    550 => (float) 55
];

$result = array_map(
    function($v1, $v2, $v3) {
        return "$v1 : $v2 : $v3";
    },
    $a, array_keys($b), $b
);

var_dump($result);
```